# How do I create two flip cards side by side in html

Tags: html, css

I'm completely new to coding - have been using w3schools to learn the basics and have come across something I can't seem to find a way around. Basically I'm a complete noob and could use some help with what is probably an extremely basic request :)

I recently did the tutorial on how to create flip cards (here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_flip_card.asp) and managed to create my own, change the font and the image etc. What I was wondering was how you'd create a grid of these in html?

I've played around and am able to create two flip cards that stack on top of one another, but is there a way to have them side by side (very basic screenshot of what I mean attached). Is there a way to do it using the template above?

I have searched this answer online but the responses are intended for people with a greater knowledge than me - I started this coding journey a couple of weeks ago!

Thanks for any help :) Really appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Float: left; so that your 2nd card will be aligned on your 1st card.

```css
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  float:left; //I just added this positioning.
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>




    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="flip-card-inner">
        <div class="flip-card-front">
          <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card-back">
          <h1>John Doe</h1> 
          <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
          <p>We love that guy</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="flip-card-inner">
        <div class="flip-card-front">
          <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
        </div>
        <div class="flip-card-back">
          <h1>John Doe</h1> 
          <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
          <p>We love that guy</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You're a star! Thank you so, so much for your help! :)

Comment: Happy to help. :) Enjoy coding

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is, put both cards into one `<div></div>`element and give this `div` a styling of `display:flex`

Full Code:
HTML:

```
 <div style="display:flex">
<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect + Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect + Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px; /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
}

/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */
.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */
.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/* Position the front and back side */
.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */
.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

/* Style the back side */
.flip-card-back {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

On JSFiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pzd9jg17/)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is make an container div and put your cards inside of it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
  <div class="card">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display: flex; //default display items in a row
}    
.container .card {
  //styling for your card
}
```